# Proper Casing in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am doing a quiz game in VB6. I need the textbox to automatically capialize the first letter but this code

```
Private Sub Anstxt_Change()
Anstxt.Text = StrConv(Anstxt.Text, vbProperCase)
End Sub
```

causes the word to invert. So instead of "Trees" it turns into "Seert"

How do I change this?

Comment: `vbProperCase` works here. Are you using right-to-left locale in Windows like hebrew or arabic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention to where the cursor is positioned in the textbox when the event `Change` occurs: its at the **start** of the textbox. Add a `Debug.Print` statement to see what's going on while you type:

```
Private Sub Anstxt_Change()
   Debug.Print StrConv(Anstxt.Text, vbProperCase)
   Anstxt.Text = StrConv(Anstxt.Text, vbProperCase)
End Sub
```

The output looks like

```
T
T
Rt
Rt
Ert
Ert
Eert
Eert
Seert
Seert
```

Two things to notice here: the `Change` event is triggered twice: once from typing and once from *changing* the value of the textbox within the `Change` event. That gives you an idea that manipulating the text of a textbox in its `Change` event isn't a good idea. I suggest to put this code in the `LostFocus` event instead.

The second thing to notice is that as the cursor is always at the **start** of the textbox, the letters you type are inserted there in front of the existing letters. So after you *change* the `.Text` property of the textbox, you should position the cursor at the end of the textbox with the `.SelStart` method:

```
Anstxt.SelStart = Len(Anstxt.Text)
```

e.g.

```
Private Sub Anstxt_Change()
   Anstxt.Text = StrConv(Anstxt.Text, vbProperCase)
   Anstxt.SelStart = Len(Anstxt.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent explanation

Comment: Agreed, excellent explanation.  I've also found that using the LostFocus event seems to be the easiest way to provide reliable results on a form where formatted input is desired.